# Working on Dictionary of Classes in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, shelve

For this example, I have a dictionary, that when I call on it, "Ember Attack" is displayed.

```
#import shelve
class Pokemon():
"""Each pokemon's attributes"""

def __init__(self):
    self.id=[]
    self.var1=[]
    self.var2=[]
    self.var3=[]
    self.var4=[]
    self.var5=[]

def __str__(self):
     showList=['id','var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5']

#dict1=shelve.open("shelve.dat")
dict1={}
dict1["Charmander"]=Pokemon()
dict1["Charmander"].var1="Ember Attack"
#dict1.sync()
print dict1["Charmander"].var1
#dict1.close()
```

However when I start using shelves instead of the dictionary, I get a blank when I call on var1.

```
import shelve

class Pokemon():
"""Each patient's attributes"""

def __init__(self):
    self.id=[]
    self.var1=[]
    self.var2=[]
    self.var3=[]
    self.var4=[]
    self.var5=[]

def __str__(self):
    showList=['id','var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5']

dict1=shelve.open("shelve.dat")
#dict1={}

dict1["Charmander"]=Pokemon()
dict1["Charmander"].var1="Ember Attack"

dict1.sync()

print dict1["Charmander"].var1

dict1.close()
```

The only difference is that I made dict1 a shelve dictionary instead of a regular dictionary. It probably has to do with memory scope or something. Anyway, can someone help me revise my code so that it will work with shelves? Thanks!

Comment: What does "work" mean?  Can you provide some hint as to what you'd like to see happen and what's not happening?

Comment: With the shelves method, I'd like to be able to call on dict1["Charmander"].var1 and have "Ember Attack" returned. When I do this now, only an empty `[]` is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict1=shelve.open("shelve.dat", writeback=True)
```

you can also specify the protocol which should improve performance

```
dict1=shelve.open("shelve.dat", protocol=2, writeback=True)
```

> Because of Python semantics, a shelf
>   cannot know when a mutable
>   persistent-dictionary entry is
>   modified. By default modified objects
>   are written only when assigned to the
>   shelf (see Example). If the optional
>   writeback parameter is set to True,
>   all entries accessed are also cached
>   in memory, and written back on sync()
>   and close(); this can make it handier
>   to mutate mutable entries in the
>   persistent dictionary, but, if many
>   entries are accessed, it can consume
>   vast amounts of memory for the cache,
>   and it can make the close operation
>   very slow since all accessed entries
>   are written back (there is no way to
>   determine which accessed entries are
>   mutable, nor which ones were actually
>   mutated).